# org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient is deprecated in Selenium 3.14.0 - What should be used instead?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, okhttp

I am currently using Selenium 3.14.0 library in which **org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient** is deprecated with no other information. Which should be used instead?

The class is already removed in the next version, 3.141.59.

I am using it with EdgeDriver Service like following:

```
final int connectionTimeout = 2 * 60 * 1000;
final int socketTimeout = 10 * 60 * 1000; // 10 minute timeout
final ApacheHttpClient.Factory clientFactory = new ApacheHttpClient.Factory(
    new HttpClientFactory(connectionTimeout, socketTimeout));

...

edgeDriverService = new EdgeDriverService.Builder()
                        .usingDriverExecutable(edgeDriver)
                        .usingAnyFreePort()
                        .build();
edgeDriverService.start();
HttpCommandExecutor executor = new HttpCommandExecutor(
    new HashMap<>(), edgeDriverService.getUrl(), clientFactory);
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(executor, new EdgeOptions());
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The HTTP client was switched to okhttp: http://square.github.io/okhttp/

This is mentioned in the Selenium Java CHANGELOG of version 3.11.0 and also you can see it in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of facts:

- The Java RemoteWebDriver client uses a *CommandExecutor* to send commands to a *RemoteWebDriver*. By default, *RemoteWebDriver* uses an *HttpCommandExecutor* which uses the Apache HttpClient library to send the commands.
- As per the *CHANGELOG*

  - The `HttpClient` implementation details were out of `HttpCommandExecutor` right from *Selenium v2.45.0*.
  - With the availability of *Selenium v3.11*, Selenium Grid was switched to use **`OkHttp`** rather than the **`Apache HttpClient`**.
  - Further with the release of *Selenium v3.141.0*, **`Apache HttpClient`** was removed from `selenium-server-standalone` which drastically
    reduced the size of selenium server distribution package.
  - Even the `apache-backed httpclient` was also removed.

Comment: this is interesting background info, but not what the question asked.. the question asked what replaced Apache HttpClient

Comment: Because of this my hub start command , which registers some custom servlets & uses custom jar (java -cp selenium-server-standalone-3.141.0.jar;mycustom.jar org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 -role hub -port 4444 -servlets com.myservlet -timeout 1800) throws an error saying                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/HttpClient . Are we supposed to include apache client jar file as an extra jar in above command ?