# org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList; with Selenium 3.5.3 Chrome 76

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, guava, junit-runner

I'm writing Selenium Junit tests with IntelliJ. The tests run ok if I trigger from test directly. However, if I trigger tests from TestRunnerSuite with JunitCore, I encountered following weird error that I did not find a solution after researching on google. Similar questions on DriverService$builder, but not my error type.

```
[main] ERROR sire.responseOrg.TestIncidents - java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:332)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:88)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at sire.responseOrg.WebDrivers.getInstance(WebDrivers.java:15)
    at sire.responseOrg.util.util1.setupChromeDriver(util1.java:51)
    at sire.responseOrg.Test1.setUp(Test1.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at ......Omitted
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:127)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:76)
    at sire.responseOrg.TestSuiteRunner.main(TestSuiteRunner.java:24)
```

I'm using Selenium 3.5.3 and chrome 76.**---> Updated to Selenium 3.141.59,and with `main` scope.**
Now getting error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.getDefaultClientFactory(HttpCommandExecutor.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.<init>(HttpCommandExecutor.java:72)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.<init>(DriverCommandExecutor.java:63)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.java:36)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:123)
    at sire.responseOrg.WebDrivers.getInstance(WebDrivers.java:15)
    at sire.responseOrg.util.SeleniumUtil.setupChromeDriver(SeleniumUtil.java:62)
    at sire.responseOrg.TestIncidents.setUp(TestIncidents.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:136)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:127)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:76)
    at sire.responseOrg.TestSuiteRunner.main(TestSuiteRunner.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.auth.Credentials
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 33 more
```

**Full pom.xml dependencies**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <description>My description</description>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.9</version>
            <scope>main</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
            <scope>main</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <scope>main</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.6</version>
            <scope>main</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.salesforce.seti</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

</project>
```

My project folder structure is

```
.src
...main
.....java
.......projectname
.........constantsFolder
.........utilFolder
...........util1.java
...........util2.java
.........Test1.java
.........TestRunnerSuite.java
.........WebDrivers.java
```

If I start test from Test1.java, the test runs regularly though with warnings

```
[main] INFO projectname.util.util1 - Set up chrome driver.
Starting ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90 (a6dcaf7e3ec6f70a194cc25e8149475c6590e025-refs/branch-heads/3770@{#1003}) on port 28755
Only local connections are allowed.
Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
[1566609934.853][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 76.
Aug 23, 2019 6:25:34 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
[main] INFO projectname.util.util1 - Navigating to https://mytest.com/
```

However, after adding a testSuiteRunner as below.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ Test1.class })
public class TestSuiteRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
        // print erros, exit etc omitted
    }
}
```

Now I get the weird error and cannot fire the chromedriver.
The webdriver I have is singleton

```
public class WebDrivers {
    private static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static WebDriver getInstance(){
        if (driver == null) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

It's my first time to work on setting everything up from grounds. I'm not sure if it's pom dependency issue, singleton webdriver issue, or something else. Could anyone share an eyesight on this and give some clues? Much appreciated.

Comment: As you are setting everything from ground. It better to update the selenium-java to 3.141.59 or Selenium 4-alpha, ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126 and if possible use Junit 5

Comment: @RahulL Hi, thanks for the reply. I updated selenium-java to 3.141.59, but no luck.

Comment: Can you post the full pom? It seems that the program cannot compile using the folder structure and program you provide.(Your classes are put under *main* folder but the dependency scope is *test*.

Comment: Also check the 'guava' dependency that is being resolved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
```

...implies that there is some **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using specifically with the **guava** *dependency*.

- You are using *chrome= 76.0*
- You are using the following:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.5.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.5.3* which is more then **2** years older.
- Your *JDK version* is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *Selenium Client v3.5.3* and *Chrome Browser v76.0*

However as per the discussions in:

- [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.builderWithExpectedSize](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/591)
- [NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList.toImmutableList()Ljava/util/stream/Collector; after upgrade to 2.0.16](https://github.com/google/error-prone/issues/528)

These issues crop up due to incompatibile **Guava** dependency.

> The current **guava** version used within **`selenium-java-3.141.59`** is **guava-25.0-jre**

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to  current levels [JDK 8u222](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Update

So presumably your main question with respect to the error:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
```

is **solved**. Congratulations.

Now, as per your question update as you are seeing the error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/auth/Credentials
```

There are two aspects.

- **NoClassDefFoundError**: *NoClassDefFoundError* in Java occurs when *Java Virtual Machine* is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time. You can find a detailed discussion in [Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104)
- `http/auth`: Traces of *http/auth* implies **`http client`** is still in use where as the [*CHANGELOG*](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG) reflects:

  - The `HttpClient` implementation details were out of `HttpCommandExecutor` right from *Selenium v2.45.0*.
  - With the availability of *Selenium v3.11*, Selenium Grid was switched to use **`OkHttp`** rather than the **`Apache HttpClient`**.
  - Further with the release of *Selenium v3.141.0*, **`Apache HttpClient`** was removed from `selenium-server-standalone` which drastically
    reduced the size of selenium server distribution package.
  - Even the `apache-backed httpclient` was also removed.
  - You can find a detailed discussion in [org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient is deprecated in selenium 3.14.0 - What should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908461/org-openqa-selenium-remote-internal-apachehttpclient-is-deprecated-in-selenium-3/54908685#54908685)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed notes. I updated selenium package to 3.141.59, and changed scope to main. But no luck and getting auth credentials error now. I updated with the error message and full pom.xml file in description. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: @user2751691 Checkout the updated answer and let me know if you need anything further.

Answer (score 2):

Remove scope from your POM. 
 test
or  main
Isn't needed for your tests to run

Answer (score 0):

used this [gauva](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/30.1.1-jre) jar with latest testng 7.3. Resolved this error also dont configure any testNG seperately. Please remove configuration if we add it in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. The following steps helped resolve it:

Go to your POM file and comment out/ remove the following dependency:

```
--> org.seleniumhq.selenium
--> selenium-java
--> 2.48.2

Check what version you have.
```

1. Then copy the latest mvn dependency which is 4.1.1 as of now
2. Perform mvn clean install (till this point it will be sufficient)
3. Perform reload all maven projects
4. Perform download sources
5. Build your project again
6. Play/ perform mvn clean install again

FYI: as per my knowledge, this issue occurs at compile time when you execute the code. Or the time when you execute a code in a new project which was compiled with different dependencies and versions earlier.