# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap error using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, guava, noclassdeffounderror, geckodriver

I am using this code and it is giving me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
        at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<clinit>FirefoxDriver.java:108)
        at Selenium_1.main(Selenium_1.java:13)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 2 more
```

Unable to solve it. I am working in eclipse, could you please help me out.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
//comment the above line and uncomment below line to use Chrome
//import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Selenium_1 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_231\\lib\\ext\\geckodriver.exe");
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chrome driver");
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            //comment the above 2 lines and uncomment below 2 lines to use Chrome
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","G:\\chromedriver.exe");
            //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            String baseUrl = "http://demo.guru99.com/test/newtours/";
            String expectedTitle = "Welcome: Mercury Tours";
            String actualTitle = "";

            // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
            driver.get(baseUrl);

            // get the actual value of the title
            actualTitle = driver.getTitle(); 

            /*
             * compare the actual title of the page with the expected one and print
             * the result as "Passed" or "Failed"
             */
            if (actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
                System.out.println("Test Passed!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Test Failed");
            }



            //close Fire fox
            driver.close();
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if you need to know anything else... i am totally stuck... HELP! HELP! HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
```

...implies that the file `com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` might be corrupted or there is some incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using specifically with the **guava** *version* / *dependency* (maven).

---

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- In the `System.setProperty()` line you need to change `webdriver.firefox.marionette` to **`webdriver.gecko.driver`**. So effectively, the line of code will be:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_231\\lib\\ext\\geckodriver.exe");
  ```
- Incase you are using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) deleting the corrup/incompatible `.m2` folder can solve your issue.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u222**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.26.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v70.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList; with Selenium 3.5.3 Chrome 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634492/org-openqa-selenium-remote-service-driverservicebuilder-createargslcom-google/57658406#57658406)

Comment: Tried but still the same issue :(

Comment: Update the question with the complete error stack trace

Comment: Done plz check now

Comment: @Gur Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: i will try this and udpate u... Thank you so much