# NoClassDefFoundError with chromedriver

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I get this error when I attempt to run a test using `chromedriver`:

> org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 30.
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
> at java.base@16.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base@16.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
> at java.base@16.0.1/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base@16.0.1/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
> at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
> at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
> at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
> Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: TestEngine with ID 'junit-jupiter' failed to discover tests
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:111)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discover(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:85)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.discover(DefaultLauncher.java:92)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
> ... 18 more
> Caused by: org.junit.platform.commons.JUnitException: ClassSelector [className = 'com.paulcarron.learningspringboot.learningspringboot.EndToEndTests'] resolution failed
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.listeners.discovery.AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.selectorProcessed(AbortOnFailureLauncherDiscoveryListener.java:39)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:102)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.run(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:82)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolver.java:113)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectorResolver.resolveSelectors(DiscoverySelectorResolver.java:45)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.JupiterTestEngine.discover(JupiterTestEngine.java:69)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.discoverEngineRoot(EngineDiscoveryOrchestrator.java:103)
> ... 25 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3334)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3359)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1990)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDefaultMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1481)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:1454)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.findMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:1304)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.isMethodPresent(ReflectionUtils.java:1205)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.hasTestOrTestFactoryOrTestTemplateMethods(IsTestClassWithTests.java:50)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.predicates.IsTestClassWithTests.test(IsTestClassWithTests.java:46)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.discovery.ClassSelectorResolver.resolve(ClassSelectorResolver.java:67)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.lambda$resolve$2(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:134)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:129)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
> at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:185)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolve(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:125)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.resolveCompletely(EngineDiscoveryRequestResolution.java:91)
> ... 30 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
> ... 54 more

I deployed `chromedriver` to the ext folder and have the correct version for my browser. What would be causing this issue? It seems to be coming from the `@BeforeClass` which can be seen below:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUp() throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "ext/chromedriver");
    service = createDefaultService();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
    Path testResults = Paths.get("build", "test-results");
    if (!Files.exists(testResults)) {
        Files.createDirectory(testResults);
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope `ext/chromedriver` in `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "ext/chromedriver")` is not a hardcoded string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### NoClassDefFoundError

**`NoClassDefFoundError`** occurs when the *JVM* is unable to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time. For example, if we have resolved a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that Class is not available during run-time then *JVM* will throw `NoClassDefFoundError`.

The error you are seeing is :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
```

This clearly indicates that *Selenium* is trying to resolve the particular class at runtime from *`org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver`* which is no more available.

---

### Solution :

Within the *`System.setProperty()`* line you need to pass the absolute path of the [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/complete/path/to/chromedriver");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823506/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-selenium-w/47845104#47845104)
- [Selenium-TestNG-Maven - Getting "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxDriver"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730321/selenium-testng-maven-getting-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-openqa-sele/50739624#50739624)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap error using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59319629/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-common-collect-immutablemap-error-usi/59319773#59319773)