# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap error using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Code trials:

```
package SeleniumSessions;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;


public class TestChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

        driver.get("https://www.google.com");

    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:118)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:106)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:48)
    at SeleniumSessions.TestChrome.main
```

Error snapshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap
```

...implies that the file `com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` might be corrupted or there is some incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using.

---

Further you need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- Instead of storing the *`chromedriver.exe`* binary right under **`C:\`** try to put it within a directory as ***`C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe`*** and change the `System.setProperty()` line accordingly. So effectively, the line of code will be:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```

Also ensure that:

- *JDK* is upgraded to current levels [JDK 8u311](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current released [***Version 4.1.3***](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v100.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=100.0.4896.60/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=100.0* (as per [chromedriver=100.0.4896.60 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/100.0.4896.60/notes.txt)).

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap error using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59319773/7429447)