# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava error while opening browser with Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nosuchmethoderror, selenium-java

I am getting this error while executing program in Eclipse.
I am trying to open fb using selenium.
Code trials:

```java
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.AddHasCasting.getAdditionalCommands(AddHasCasting.java:38)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.getExtraCommands(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver$ChromeDriverCommandExecutor.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:94)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:50)
    at Practice.OpenBrowser.main(OpenBrowser.java:15)
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap.of(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap;
```

...implies that the file `com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap` might be corrupted or there is some incompatibility between the version of the binaries you are using specifically with the **guava** *version* / *dependency* (maven).

---

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

- In the `System.setProperty()` line you have passed the absolute location of the ChromeDriver/GeckoDriver as follows:

  ```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\path\\to\\chromedriver.exe");
  ```
- Incase you are using [maven](/questions/tagged/maven) deleting the corrup/incompatible `.m2` folder can solve your issue.
- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [JDK 8u351](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8u211-later-archive-downloads.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v109.0](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=109.0.5414.74/) level.
- *Chrome Browser* is updated to  current *chrome=109.0* (as per [chromedriver=102.0.5005.61 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/notes.txt)).

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussion in:

- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap error using GeckoDriver Firefox through Selenium in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59319773/7429447)
- [org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.createArgs()Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList; with Selenium 3.5.3 Chrome 76](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57634492/org-openqa-selenium-remote-service-driverservicebuilder-createargslcom-google/57658406#57658406)