# What is the alternative for ApacheHttpClient class in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, remotewebdriver

I have code as below

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new HttpCommandExecutor(new HashMap<String, CommandInfo>(),
                new URL(URL), new Factory() {
                    private HttpClientBuilder builder;
                    {
                        builder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
                        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxy,proxyport);
                        System.out.println(proxy);
                        builder.setProxy(proxy);                        
                        System.out.println(builder);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public HttpClient createClient(URL url) {
                        return new ApacheHttpClient(builder.build(), url);
                    }
```

but as the ApacheHttpClient class has been deprecated what is the alternative for ApacheHttpClient  class to use in the above code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54908461/org-openqa-selenium-remote-internal-apachehttpclient-is-deprecated-in-selenium-3

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpClient instead of ApacheHttpClient